# can't check the CheckBox in QlistWidget using Pyqt5 the system display an error in python

Tags: python, checkbox, qlistwidget

I have a code that display items in a QlistWidget  and beside each item exist a check box that the user can checked in for future task.

**the Problem is that when the user check the CheckBox before it click on the item Text**

The system crash and display the below error :

> line 126, in FileListSelected
>   Item=self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem().text()
>
> builtins.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

## code:

```
 def FileListSelected(self):             # Function to select the desired file from the list in the left panel
        print(self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem())
        Item=self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem().text()     
        return Item
```

what is the error in my function ?

Answer (score 0):

`self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem()` returns None when no item is currently selected.

Normally it would return a list widget item which has a `.text()` method, None does not so it fails.

You can fix the error like so:

```
def FileListSelected(self):
    print(self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem())
    Item=self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem()
    return Item.text() if Item else None
```

However it's probably better to add a method to the QCheckBox that returns its parent QListWidgetItem

Comment: how to write a method to the QCheckBox that returns its parent QListWidgetItem ?